# quotation mark break ctags for javascript

Tags: javascript, ctags, exuberant-ctags

ctags cannot tag a function if it is defined after a line that has a quotation mark in the regexp.

```
var aa=/'asdf/;
function bb(){
  return 0;
}
```

Then the output tags file has nothing, nor aa and bb are tagged.

Actually, there is a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/bugs/208/) filed for this problem in 2008. It says this will be fixed in next release. But looks like it is still there in my ctags which is:

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: Have you tried `/\'asdf/`?

Comment: Still not work. Thanks

Comment: `/\u0027asdf/` is semantically equivalent to `/'asdf/`.

Comment: It looks like you've done a good job of finding a minimal testcase.  I'd file a new bug with your testcase and a link to the closed bug.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. It works, but I have much legacy codes. Is this the only way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Universal-ctags (https://ctags.io) can capture aa and bb well.

```
$ ./ctags -o - /tmp/foo.js  
aa  /tmp/foo.js /^var aa=\/'asdf\/;$/;" v
bb  /tmp/foo.js /^function bb(){$/;"    f
```